Upgraded xcode and increased deployment target. Now i am getting "Cannot find type 'MessagingDelegate' in scope" error
I upgraded xcode to 15 and increased deployment to 17. I also increased deployment target in my pods folders to 17. Now when i try to build my project i am getting the error "Cannot find type MessagingDelegate in scope" error in my AppDelegate.swift class. Which MessagingDelegate class belongs to FirebaseMessaging and it was working up until now.
I have these modules imported in the class :
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

import Firebase

I get an error on this line
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {

I tried to import FirebaseMessaging on the top of the class and when i try to build project i got the error "No such module FirebaseMessaging".
I tried updating cocoapods but it still did not change.
How can i fix this error ?

This doesn't answer your question, but I would strongly recommend dropping cocoapods entirely and using the swift package manager approach to Firebase.
